# proof on similarity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you please help me with the following problem?
Let $A$ be an $n$$\times$$n$ complex matrix. Prove that $A$ is similar to $B$, which is an $n$ $\times$ $n$ real matrix, if and only if $A$ is similar to its conjugate transpose.
I have been trying to solve it for quite a long time, I tried to expand the definition of similarity but I did not  manage to get anything useful. I have no better idea.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: I guess I do not understand you exactly. Why should I prove that $A$ is similar to $A$$*$, if that is a given condition?

Comment: Sorry for the not exactly understandable sentence then. Anyway, it is true, the only question is how to be proven,

Comment: Yes, that is what I am willing to prove. As far as I am concerned, that is the task. Thanks for your help. I ask a friend of mine whether I misunderstood the task.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Not every (complex) matrix is similar to its conjugate transpose; for instance $\mathbf iI$ is not. But every (real or otherwise) matrix is similar to its transpose. I think the real question is to prove $A\sim B\;\Leftrightarrow\; A\sim B^*$, where $B^*=B^\top$ since $B$ is supposed real; this is of course trivial if you already know $B\sim B^\top$ . The question is just badly formulated: "its" is unclear.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see, thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: Or maybe the question is: $A$ is similar to _some_ real matrix if and only if $A\sim A^*$. The the question is just unclear by giving the name $B$ to real matrix, even though it is nowhere further referenced. That way the question is more interesting; the "if" direction is not immediate.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: thanks for your contribution to the solution. But the real question is A∼B⇔A∼A*, as Algebraic Pavel mentioned.

Comment: You are right. It is completely senseless to name the real matrix.

Comment: So the question is: A (which is n dimensional complex matrix) is similar to its conjugate transpose if and only if it is similar to a real n dimensional matrix (which was called B).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following facts are useful:

- (1) For any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $A\sim A^T$.
- (2) For any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $A\sim B$ for some $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ if and only if $A\sim\bar{A}$.

So if $A\sim B$ for some real $B$, then 
$$A\stackrel{(2)}\sim\bar{A}\stackrel{(1)}\sim\bar{A}^T=A^*.$$
On the other hand, if $A\sim A^*$, then
$$
A\sim A^*=\bar{A}^T\stackrel{(1)}\sim\bar{A}\stackrel{(2)}\sim B
$$
for some real $B$.

---

Fact (1) can be shown by establishing a similarity transformations between elementary Jordan blocks and their transposes. If $J_{\lambda}$ is an elementary Jordan block and $R$ is the "reversal" matrix (an identity with flipped columns (or rows)), then $R^{-1}J_{\lambda}R=J_{\lambda}^T$ (note that $R^{-1}=R^T$).

For fact (2), the tricky part is to show that if $A\sim\bar{A}$, then $A$ is similar to a real matrix (the other direction of the equivalence is easy). If $A\sim\bar{A}$, then both $A$ and $\bar{A}$ have the same Jordan form $J$. But since both $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are similar to $J$, for each elementary Jordan block $J_{\lambda}\in\mathbb{C}^{k\times k}$, there must be a "matching" Jordan block $J_{\bar{\lambda}}$. The tricky part is to show that the "paired" Jordan blocks
$$
\pmatrix{J_{\lambda}&0\\0&J_{\bar{\lambda}}}
$$
are similar to a real matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{K&I_2&&\\
          &K&I_2&\\
          &&\ddots&\ddots\\
          &&&K&I_2\\&&&&K}\in\mathbb{R}^{2k\times 2k},
\quad
K:=\pmatrix{\Re\lambda&\Im\lambda\\-\Im\lambda&\Re\lambda},
$$
where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity (this leads to the so-called [*real Jordan form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices)).

Comment: Is there an easy proof for (1)?

Comment: @Berci Yes. It uses simply the reversal matrix.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Thank you very much for your help.That is a great proof!

Comment: @Berciboy You are welcome!